# Unable to downgrade npm version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm using node version 10.19.0, I have npm v9.6.2 and they are incompatible

```
andrei399@ATUDOR-PF442EJD:~$ nvm use 10.19.0
Now using node v10.19.0 (npm v)
andrei399@ATUDOR-PF442EJD:~$ npm install -g npm@8.11.0
ERROR: npm v9.6.2 is known not to run on Node.js v10.19.0. You'll need to upgrade
to a newer Node.js version in order to use this version of npm. This version of
npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You
can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
```

I tried switching to node 19 and install npm 8.11 from there, but that didn't seem to help with node 10's version of npm

```
andrei399@ATUDOR-PF442EJD:~$ nvm use 19
Now using node v19.2.0 (npm v8.11.0)
andrei399@ATUDOR-PF442EJD:~$
andrei399@ATUDOR-PF442EJD:~$ npm install -g npm@8.11.0
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

changed 14 packages, and audited 202 packages in 1s

11 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

1 high severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
andrei399@ATUDOR-PF442EJD:~$ nvm use 10
Now using node v10.19.0 (npm v)
andrei399@ATUDOR-PF442EJD:~$ npm
ERROR: npm v9.6.2 is known not to run on Node.js v10.19.0. You'll need to upgrade
to a newer Node.js version in order to use this version of npm. This version of
npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You
can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
```

Even tried with -location=global instead of -g, but of course, that didn't help either.

Comment: Why are you using Node 10? It is 2 years into [end-of-life](https://github.com/nodejs/release#end-of-life-releases)

Comment: Uninstall and then reinstall is often a good solution.

Comment: @pilchard the project I'm working on uses node 10, there isn't anything I can do about it

Comment: `I'm working on uses node 10`  Node is usually pretty much backwards compatible, in most cases code written for older versions of node will just work on newer, the main issues I've had in the past when upgrading is mainly been with binary packages were dev's haven't yet updated.  Of course a binary package that's no longer maintained would be a pita.  It might be worth giving it a go, make a copy of the project and try.  You never know you might find it wasn't that hard upgrading as you might have thought.

Comment: Seen as your using nvm,  did you try -> `nvm install --latest-npm`  from what I can gather this should install the latest `npm` compatible with the version your running.